# split dataframe rows into multiple for fractional values

Tags: python, pandas

sample data:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'split_me': [1.5, 2, 4, 3.2], 'copy_me': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
out = pd.DataFrame({'split_me': [1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.2], 'copy_me': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']})

sample:  # input
    split_me    copy_me
0   1.5 A
1   2.0 B
2   4.0 C
3   3.2 D

out:  # desired output
    split_me    copy_me
0   1.0 A
1   0.5 A
2   1.0 B
3   1.0 B
4   1.0 C
5   1.0 C
6   1.0 C
7   1.0 C
8   1.0 D
9   1.0 D
10  1.0 D
11  0.2 D
```

I tried using something like `sample.loc[sample.index.repeat(sample['split_me'])]`. However this only repeats for integers and a value like 1.9 returns 1 row when I need it to return 2, and it leaves values in `split_me` unchanged, whereas I need to duplicate the rows, allocate 1 to `split_me` if it's greater than 1, otherwise allocate the value.

I can't think of a way to do this without getting loopy and complicated, my best approach is to `ceil(split_me)` and then run `repeat`, but I still need a way to allocate the value to duplicated rows. Looking for a simpler solution if anyone has it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can do this

```
out = sample.reindex(sample.index.repeat(np.ceil(sample['split_me'])))
out['new'] = 1
con = ~out['copy_me'].duplicated(keep='last') & (out['split_me']%1!=0)
out['new'] = out['new'].mask(con, out['split_me']%1)
out
Out[195]: 
   split_me copy_me  new
0       1.5       A  1.0
0       1.5       A  0.5
1       2.0       B  1.0
1       2.0       B  1.0
2       4.0       C  1.0
2       4.0       C  1.0
2       4.0       C  1.0
2       4.0       C  1.0
3       3.2       D  1.0
3       3.2       D  1.0
3       3.2       D  1.0
3       3.2       D  0.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sample = pd.DataFrame({'split_me': [1.5, 2, 4, 3.2], 'copy_me': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})


def expanded_index(s, c):
    index = np.repeat(1.0, s // 1)
    if (s % 1) > 0:
        index = np.append(index, [s % 1])
    return pd.Series(c, index)


res = pd.concat([expanded_index(s, c) for s, c in zip(sample["split_me"], sample["copy_me"])])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
1.0    A
0.5    A
1.0    B
1.0    B
1.0    C
1.0    C
1.0    C
1.0    C
1.0    D
1.0    D
1.0    D
0.2    D
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom repeat function

```
repeat_float = lambda x: ([1.] * int(x // 1)) + ([x % 1] if x % 1 != 0 else [])
out = df['split_me'].apply(repeat_float).explode().astype(float) \
                    .to_frame().join(df['copy_me']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    split_me copy_me
0        1.0       A
1        0.5       A
2        1.0       B
3        1.0       B
4        1.0       C
5        1.0       C
6        1.0       C
7        1.0       C
8        1.0       D
9        1.0       D
10       1.0       D
11       0.2       D
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use [`np.modf`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html) to separate the fractional and integral parts of `split_me`, then create a new Series of 1s based on the only the [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) of the integral portion. [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) the non-zero fractional parts, [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) to get into the expected order, lastly [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back the columns and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to restore the range index:

```
fractional, integral = np.modf(sample['split_me'])
df = (
    pd.Series(1, index=integral.index.repeat(integral), name=integral.name)
        .append(fractional[fractional.ne(0)]).sort_index(kind='stable')
        .to_frame().join(sample[['copy_me']]).reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

`df`:

```
    split_me copy_me
0        1.0       A
1        0.5       A
2        1.0       B
3        1.0       B
4        1.0       C
5        1.0       C
6        1.0       C
7        1.0       C
8        1.0       D
9        1.0       D
10       1.0       D
11       0.2       D
```

---

Setup and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sample = pd.DataFrame({
    'split_me': [1.5, 2, 4, 3.2],
    'copy_me': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
})
```